# Error loading RubyGems plugin ".../plugins/yard_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- .../lib/rubygems_plugin.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, yard

I got:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/plugins/yard_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/yard-0.9.34/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb (LoadError)
```

While running `bundle` on the `rails/rails` repository.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was either to `gem install yard` or add `gem "yard"` to the Gemfile and run `bundle`.

So installing yard was the solution